# Apache LAMP permisson issues on Ubuntu server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions, ubuntu-10.04

I have been trawling the internet for a few days now and think I've tried almost everything to get some virtual hosts set up on my Ubuntu server but everything short of `chmod 777` on the webroot fails.

I have my default Apache conf pointing at /home/server/public_html with the the settings show below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/server/public_html/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/server/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have then created a virtual host for a project I'm working on say for example project.name.co.uk.conf and inside there I have the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://www.local.dirty-briefs.co.uk
    ServerAlias local.project-name.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /home/server/public_html/project-name/
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

I then ran `sudo a2ensite project.name.co.uk.conf`.
I'm working on a windows 7 machine using samba to access the files on the server.  I added the project.name.co.uk to my windows hosts file however not matter what I do I get 403 permission errors.

## edit

Thought id add the tail of the Apache error log in case it was useful

```
*==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
[Sat Jun 11 13:22:23 2011] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] PHP Warning:          require(/home/server/public_html/dirty-briefs/site/protected/config/main.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/server/public_html/dirty-briefs/framework/base/CApplication.php on line 120
[Sat Jun 11 13:22:23 2011] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/server/public_html/dirty-briefs/site/protected/config/main.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/server/public_html/dirty-briefs/framework/base/CApplication.php on line 120*
```

It may also be worth mentioning I'm working with Yii the PHP framework I have a .htaccess file that lives in my site folder with the following inside

```
    # Disable directory browsing
    Options All -Indexes

    # File types
    AddType application/x-font-woff .eot .ttf       # Font-Face


    # URL Rewriting
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Site Maintenance
    # RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.0\.2\.2
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html [L]

            
    # LOCAL 
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^local.project-name.co.uk
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index-local.php/$1
    # -----

    # PRODUCTION
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^project-name.co.uk
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.project-name.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www.project-name.co.uk
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php/$1
    # -----
    </IfModule>
```

I tailed the Apache error and access logs and found I was getting perm errors on importing files inside my PHP script due to permission errors.

I have read about checking what user and group Apache is running under, which are www-data www-data so I'm guessing Apache basically doesn't have perms to access the files under /home/server/public_html unless I give the folder 777 perms which I don't want so I'm just wondering if anyone can spot what I'm doing wrong or advise on anything I can try to get this working

Comment: Please post `ls -l /home` and `ls -l /home/server`

Answer (score 2):

This folder layout is a litle confusing. Your default vhost directive specifes `/home/server/public_html/` as the `DocumentRoot`, but then you specify a *subfolder* of it as the root of your application. This isn't an optimal configuration. Try moving the site out of `public_html` into its own folder (`/home/server/project` or somesuch) and setting the `DocumentRoot` accordingly.

Once it's moved, you don't need `777` permissions to make it accessible, though it does need to be readable by `www-data`. Try:

```
chmod -R 644 /home/server/project   
find /home/server/project -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \+
```

This will make everything world-readable and all the folders traversable (setting the execute bit on folders does this).

One other thing: `ServerName` doesn't use the `http://` prefix. You should remove that from the configuration and leave just the domain name.

Restart your apache after this changes and you should be able to reach the site with your given host name.

Comment: Hey thanks for your amazing answer!! The reason i had the projects under public_html was just so everything was organised, maybe public_html was a bad name but would you still suggest i moved them out into the root under /home/server then point the DocumentRoot of my virtualHost at /home/server/project-name/ in turn should i then point the default at /home/server ?

Comment: Certainly, keeping all of your sites in one location is no bad thing, but the default `DcoumentRoot` doesn't need to be (and shouldn't be) a *parent* of the other vhost roots. Remember: any requests for domains that don't match the `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` of your vhosts will be served by the default one. With your original setup, it might be possible for people to subvert security measures in the sub-vhost by accessing the same files though the parent one.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for clearing that up for me, so perhaps what ill do is revert the default back to /var/www/ then create virtual hosts to point to /home/server/sites/project-name

Ill have a go at that now and let you know the outcome, Thanks again!

Comment: chmod -R 644 /home/server/project when running that is it weird that i need sudo i mean i dont think it is but as i step through this i just wanna make sure im not missing something causing the problem you know

Comment: YOU LEGEND!! That worked a treat

Comment: Glad to help. :) - `chmod` doesn't need superuser permissions, per se, but you do need to own the file(s) for it to work, so if you;re logged in as `server` and all the files in the folder you're working on are owned by `server`, it'll work. Otherwise you need to sudo it. (Having write permission on the file isn't enough, you need to own it.)

Comment: :( i spoke to soon anything less than 775 is still giving me 403 error i was working earlier and i really cant tell you what has changed

Comment: could it possibly be something to do with samba? i only say that because as soon as i edit the files on my windows machine i get the perm error again??

Comment: To my knowledge, Samba doesn't typically alter the permissions on *existing* files, though you can set the umask of newly created files on a per-share basis. Can you edit in the `[share]` portion of your smb.conf? That might give some hints.

Comment: Yeah i had the usmask set to the correct perms, in fact they were higher than the perms i was recursibly setting for the folders anyway so was stumped with that... I have stopped putting off the unavoidable and formatted my windows box to ubuntu desktop 11.04 now and viola no problems.  I know thats not helpful for anyone reading this and i would like to know what was causing the error but i just ran out of ideas in the end

Answer (score 1):

You can give Apache the right to access the files without setting them to world-can-do-everything (rwxrwxrwx or 777), you would only need to give it permission to read the files so that the PHP executable can read them. You may need to give execution rights too if PHP checks for that. The better way would be to change ownership with `chown www-data:www-data <file>` then you can give Apache full rights and no rights to anyone else (except root) with `chmod 700` (or `chmod u+rwx <file>; chmod go-rwx <file>` if you prefer to use mnemonic codes rather than the bit-pattern based ones).

If you have other sites running from the same Apache install (and so also running as `www-data`) and you want to keep them separated s one site is to some extent protected by the others, then look into using `suPHP` ([as provided by this package in Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libapache2-mod-suphp)). It is less efficient than the bog-standard mod_php (though not by much unless you are on severely constrained hardware) but gives you that extra layer of protection between users/sites by making it harder for them (accidentally or otherwise) to affect each other or read each other's stuff. Each script gets run by a process acting as the user that owns it, so a php file owned by user1 gets run as user1 and no other user (even www-data or what-ever scripts usually run as) needs to have *any* access to it. You may encounter other permissions errors from suphp until you have things set right, as it defaults to insisting certain security checks pass (like directories and scripts not being world writeable) before running any script.

<sub>ps. re: `require(/home/server/public_html/dirty-briefs/site/protected/config/main.php): failed` - coffee stained meeting briefing notes, or something else?!</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You probably need execute access on `/home/server` so the Apache user can traverse inside it to read the `public_html` folder (which should be other-readable).

```
# If not already drwx--x--x...
chmod o+x /home/server
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply i had the relevant perms set for those folders

Answer (score -1):

It is probably a seLinux problem.

EDIT:

To be sure you can set seLinux to permissive mode and try again. If you were working on RedHat I would recommend using system-config-selinux but I dont know a tool for that in Ubuntu

Comment: And would you elaborate on how to fix the problem, rather than just blaming something?

Comment: I cannot without access to the server. I guess knowing the problem will help.

Comment: Before down voting make sure that some one else is talking about same issue with better answer.

Comment: the downvote was probably not because who-ever voted didn't think it was an selinux issue (though it most likely isn't IMO), it is because answers of the form of your pre-edit answer ("It is probably an *X* problem.") are rarely useful to the question asker. Some more detail on how to verify that *X* is/isn't the issue and what might need to be done to address the problem if it is that, would make the response far more helpful.